# Complext event structure in FIWARE Generic Enabler CEP - Proton

Tags: complex-event-processing, fiware

I'd like to use Proton as CEP GE in my FI-WARE architecture.

I ask your help because I have an event that has a complex structure and I would like to understand how can I define it and the EPA that should use it.

I check in documents you provide in this wiki
https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_User_and_Programmer_Guide
and then
[forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification)
and
http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.ArchitectureDescription.Data.CEP

but I don't find anything about attributes of type object in event configuration or EPA (Event Process Agent) configuration or how set up the event description using REST api.

the json structure of incoming event is this (I know that name attribute here is missing)

```
{"contextElements":[
    {"type":"ADD",
    "isPattern":false,
    "id":"ADD_MESSAGE_com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.model.MBMessage_111516",
    "attributes":[
        {"name":"id_","type":"long","value":"32302"},
        {"name":"companyId","type":"long","value":"10157"},
        {"name":"groupId","type":"long","value":"10184"},
        {"name":"userId","type":"long","value":"10201"},
        {"name":"date","type":"date","value":"12-mar-2015"},
        {"name":"type","type":"string","value":"ADD_MESSAGE"},
        {"name":"className","type":"string","value":"com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.model.MBMessage"},
        {"name":"classPK","type":"string","value":"111516"},
        {"name":"classUuid","type":"string","value":"9cd599c5-e01e-417d-9118-a636beed7145"},
        {"name":"model","type":"string","value":"{32302}"}
        ]}
    ],
"updateAction":"APPEND"}
```

The EPA should then check the "value" of "name":"groupId" "attributes" field.
I don't think is easy to do it using Proton UI (http://130.206.81.23:8080/AuthoringTool/Main.html). I created there a new project named is3_like_eng_test.

Could you address me to a resource that deeply explain how create the proton project json file I need also.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To define an event, you need to create a new Event in the UI, and add to it a list of attributes, each has a name and a type.
In this [tutorial](https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=58) you can see an example of event definition.

This event can be used as input event for EPAs. In the tutorial mentioned above, you can see complete CEP application definition, and runtime examples.

Later, at runtime, you can send the CEP input events using [REST api](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification#Receiving_Events_API). There are three supported formats:

- Flat JSON. Example:

  `{"Name":"TrafficReport", "volume":"1000"}`
- Tag delimited format. Example:

  `Name=TrafficReport;volume=1000;`
- NGSI XML - see example in the above link.

Comment: Thank you. So you tell to me that events have to be "simple" attributes list inside the json event, aren't you? I don't have control of input json string so I decided to use a json broker to translate the json I posted to a json that CEP likes.

Comment: Yes, the FIWARE CEP expects input events to have simple, flat, structure