# Fiware's CEP and arrays within JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, fiware, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to integrate CEP with a mailing service (Mandrill) that has specific requisits in terms of how variables are structured within the JSON object that is sent through http, requiring a complex structure.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234792/complext-event-structure-in-fiware-generic-enabler-cep-proton) that Fiware's CEP only takes flat JSONs as inputs. But maybe it's possible to create complex outputs. I've read [elsewhere](https://jira.fiware.org/browse/HELP-2523) that CEP used to support array inputs, so it still supports arrays.

On [Proton User Guide](https://forge.fiware.org/docman/view.php/47/5272/ProtonUserGuide-FI-WAREv3.5.pdf)(pdf) I've read that "array of arrays are supported" and that you need to specify the Dimension attribute of a variable to do so, within Events.

So I'd like ask: What exactly are the arrays mentioned on the manual, if the inputs are only flat?
What is the 'Dimension' attribute responsible for? And why is it's value limited to 0, 1 or 2 ? Maybe it's the depth of the array.

I only ask such a vague question here because I wasn't able to find more info or examples on arrays in CEP elsewhere. Maybe there is an information source I'm missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dimension is the dimension of the array, so you can have matrices (dimension = 2) and a cube (dimension = 3)

You can write an array like this:

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

The object "employees" is an array containing three objects. Each object is a record of a person (with a first name and a last name).

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I thought that would be the explanation.
But unfortunaly fiware's CEP doesn't recieve arrays anymore right?
We will be parsing the json object inside our own api and sending an email from there, instead of using Mandrill.

Comment: According to Proton User Guide, page 12, arrays are supported and arrays of arrays too. Have you read something different?

Comment: Yes. In the first link I quoted in the question, Tali Haham mentions in a comment: "... the FIWARE CEP expects input events to have simple, flat, structure", as an unswer to the comment the person asked. And in the second link she explicitly says: "Arrays are not supported for input event attributes". The dates are pretty reacent, but who knows, things change.
I also read in the Proton User Guide that it did support arrays, that's why I was also a bit confused and searched about it.
My original question above has several links to where I read those things.